# Calculate length of first argument in java

Tags: java, arguments

I want to print the length of the first `argument(args[0])` but getting `ArrayOutOfBountException` :

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        args[0] = "Hello";
        System.out.println(args[0].length());

    }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at Main.main(Main.java:3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write the code,

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        args[0] = "Hello";
        System.out.println(args[0].length());

    }
}
```

At this point `args[0]="Hello";`, If your args a String array is not initialized then, while execute I'm supposed to think that you may have used the command in such a way `java Main` to execute your basic program.

Which cause the error, You have not passed any argument through command line so your `String[] args` is not initialized yet and it is not able to store your String "Hello" inside array `args[0]` and you are trying to print an empty array and throw the Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at Main.main(Main.java:3)
```

**Update Answer:**
Now Yes, You can use that to verify the String args length before print.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        if(args.length !=0){
           System.out.println(args[0].length());
        }else{
          args = new String[1]; //Initilize first
          args[0] = "Hello";    //Store value in array element 
          System.out.println(args[0].length()); //Print it.
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I am not providing any argument while execution, I am providing arguments in program itself.

Comment: Yes, Because you are not providing any argument through an Command line which means your `String args[]` has not been initialized, which cause an error. As you may aware that before storing data in an array we need to initialize them first so either you need to initialize programmatically or through the command line.

Comment: @ShantanuUdasi and why do you want to use the String array then? What happens if you have a boolean argument? I don"t get it. You can define all things in the main() method, no need to reuse the `args[]` array

Comment: Alright! Thanks first of all for the help! I am using a automated input application for testing this program. As Dushyant told me I have initialized args[] by nextLine(), now it is working perfectly.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @AKSW, The purpose of learning behind this then it's good otherwise I suggest you create a new array and perform operations on it.

Comment: @ShantanuUdasi you should read about parameterized test in JUnit or TestNG then. At least for later projects this is the "better" way

Comment: Definitely AKSW! Being a beginner in Java I would like to complete it first. I would surely check  JUnit or TestNG. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, check if there is an argument. Then print the length. It's not a good idea to change the values in the argument array either. Something like

```
if (args.length > 0) {
    System.out.println(args[0].length);
} else {
    System.out.println(0);
}
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here array of String does not have any initialized objects and **args** has 0 element. That's why it is recommended to check whether does args have any element or not. Then, proceed further accordingly. This is how code looks like.

```
 public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    if(args.length !=0){
       // do something
    }else{
      // args doesn't have element.
      return ;
  }  
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check first if an argument is even present.If there is no argument passed and you try to access any element, it will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Also, you should avoid assign any hardcoded value to the elements in array. The code to access 1st element can be something like below:-

```
if(args.length>0){
 System.out.println(args[0].length());
 }
```